# How do I create a list of unique entries while also eliminating entries that are siblings?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

- I have a spreadsheet used for after school pickup procedures.
- QR Codes are scanned into the "Entry" Sheet.
- Scan is student ID.
- Student IDs are linked to student name, teacher, grade, and
  siblings' ID numbers.
- I want to run some analytics on students.
- "Analytics" sheet pulls in a unique() of student IDs scanned.
- However, some are repeated due to the siblings' code also being
  scanned.
- I need "Analytics" sheet, column A to exclude values that are
  siblings (columns B through E).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FteL9g1kMd9CFmzg_Ly3uNy05ZlGA86_YPi-1cqhac0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Entry!B2:B, 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(Entry!B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:E))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I've noticed that your answers appearing in the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) a few times recently. This answer, for instance, is currently under review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23983169). I think this is either happening because your answers typically are being considered [code-only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300837/1364007) and somebody is flagging them (they often don't have any explanation, and instead have screenshots), or because they're short so the system is automatically creating reviews for them.

Comment: Wow!  Incredible.  Thank you so much!